# is there an easy way to delete all dead tracks?

Tags: tracking

I have a tracked out video and a lot of tracks failed. Is there a button or something to delete all the dead tracking points? It's a long process to go through and find all of them and delete them.

Comment: *Dead tracks* are markers that have not been solved?

Comment: I mean, tracks that have lost their point somewhere in the track